# Travelling to UK as an unaccompanied minor

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, london, minors, england

I would be turning 18 in July and wish to travel to the UK in June. I hold an Indian passport. I would be travelling alone. I have had 2 previous UK visas (both now expired) which said I cannot travel without my parents.

Would I be able to travel alone? What would be the required documents to travel alone?

Comment: Will you be staying with someone, such as a relative, who will take care of you? See "Travelling alone" at (https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18)

Comment: I would be visiting my sister who goes to university there and lives at a student only accommodation

Comment: Please add that information to the question.

Comment: @ExemptFan If your sister lives in student accomodation on campus, you might want to get confirmation that the university will allow you to stay with her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of visas for under-18 visitors to the UK. The one you have used before is intended for travel with an adult, typically a parent.

There is another form for unaccompanied minors, intended for an under-18 traveling, for example, to visit a relative. You will need to prove you have somewhere suitable to stay, provide specific information about your sister, and have written consent from your parents. See [Travelling alone](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18). With your parents' consent your sister will be, in effect, a temporary guardian while you are in the UK.

As was the case for the accompanied visa, you will need to show you can support yourself during your time in the UK and return home without working or public funds.